# Android - How to Open Another Activity When you click a button

Tags: android

I am trying to open an `Activity` that contains a few **TextView's** and **EditText's**, my code was working perfectly earlier, but now when I click the button to open the `Activity`, it says "Unfortunately ... has stopped!". Here is a code snippet:

```
Button address=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setOrChangeAddress);
address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, ChangeAddressFromAddressButton.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
            }
        });
```

Please could you help me!

#### Edit

LogCat output:

```
07-18 15:43:31.470: D/(3072): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa580bea0, tid 3072
07-18 15:43:35.020: D/AndroidRuntime(3072): Shutting down VM
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): Process: com.example.policealert, PID: 3072
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.policealert.ChangeAddressFromAddressButton }
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at com.example.policealert.MainActivityWithButtons$1.onClick(MainActivityWithButtons.java:34)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-18 15:43:35.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

EDIT:

Sorry, here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.policealert"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivityWithButtons"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangeAddressFromAddressButton"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_address_from_address_button" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationSelectFromAlertButton"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_location_select_from_alert_button" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationSelectFromAlertButtons"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_location_select_from_alert_buttons" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83629/discussion-on-question-by-kyle-brooks-android-how-to-open-another-activity-whe).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting an `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`. The activity is not found in your Manifest.xml file.

You should include

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.policealert.ChangeAddressFromAddressButton"   
     android:label="@string/title_activity_change_address_from_address_button">
</activity>
```

in your Manifest.xml file and change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, ChangeAddressFromAddressButton.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.policealert.ChangeAddressFromAddressButton");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No, it didn't, unfortunately

Comment: Is ChangeAddressFromAddressButton.java under the same folder where MainActivityWithButtons.java resides? If it still doesn't work, could you please clean and build the project again?

Comment: Do you mean delete everything and start again?

Comment: What if I copied the code into a Word doc and then copy it back?

Comment: No. I am not asking you to start again. If you are using eclipse, then go to Project -> clean -> OK. I you are using Android Studio, then go to Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: They aren't because that's how Eclipse puts them, the one under src and the other under res

Comment: Ohhh haha Ok I am waiting for the emulator to start

Comment: I cant help you further without having a look into your complete project.

Comment: You can if you need to

Comment: I've just sent it, I hope everything came through, I couldn't send it zipped, so I had to send the individual files together

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't Gmail wasn't letting me

Answer (score 0):

please write this code in manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ChangeAddressFromAddressButton"
  >
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added **ChangeAddressFromAddressButton** Activity in your manifest file as you are getting **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found** Exception
.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.your.package.name.ChangeAddressFromAddressButton"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @KyleBrooks, Can you please do build and clean project and then run again ?

Answer (score 0):

In `ChangeAddressFromAddressButton.java`, you were trying to instantiate the views before the `activity_change_address_from_address_button.xml` was actually loaded.

Try this. It will work.

```
Button save;
TextView currentAddress;
EditText addressNew;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_address_from_address_button);

    save =(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    currentAddress =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrAddress);
    addressNew=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbNewAddress);

    // your logic
}
```